# Should I use the same variables throught entire Unit Test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit5

I am creating Unit Tests in Java and for each method, I create the same lists, variables, etc. On the other hand, of course I thought that I could create all of these variables as global and set their values in the `setup()` method (in `@Before`), but I am not sure if the values may be changed when running tests due to multithreading, etc. So, what is the best way for this situation?

Comment: Also, if possible you might consider using the more up-to-date JUnit 5 ("Jupiter"). Your annotations would then be `@BeforeEach` and `@BeforeAll`. It also supports nested test classes, parameterized tests, extensions, fancy stuff like `@DisplayName("…")` … and it allows you to even exchange the complete test engine—if you should need to.

Comment: Yes, I also thought that and of course can use @BeforeEach and @BeforeAll. However, I just need to be clarified about the Unit Test convention for re-using the same variables (e.g. just defining once in @BeforeEach **OR** @BeforeAll, clear the variables on  `@AfterEach`. So, what is the proper approach for this situation? I think it is a really common situation and there must be a general approach for that. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to worry about. JUnit will create a new instance of your test class, and then run each `@Before` method, and only then run the `@Test` method, and it does that song and dance routine all over again **for every `@Test` annotated method in that class**. You're using `@Before` exactly as it was intended: It's for storing initialization code that is required for all the tests in that test class.

JUnit does it this way because 'test independence' is nice to have: Tests, preferably, fail or pass independent of the ordering in which you execute them.

Every so often the init process is so expensive that it's not worth it to pay the 'cost' of running it over and over again for every test. The annotation `@BeforeClass` exists specifically for *that* purpose. The javadoc of `@BeforeClass` even spells out that this compromises test independence and should therefore only be used if the setup work you do within such a method is sufficiently expensive (computationally or otherwise) to make that tradeoff.

In other words:

Your worries about test independence are real, but they apply to `@BeforeClass`. `@Before` doesn't suffer from this problem; that code is re-run for every test.

NB: You can toss all this out the window if you have `static` stuff going on. Don't have static stuff in test code unless you really know what you're doing. I assume you don't have that in which case - carry on, your tests are independent.

Comment: Thanks a lot, any example code that show proper usage?

Comment: I did not understand the difference between `@BeforeClass` and `@Before`. Any clarification pls?

Comment: all methods with `@Before` are run before __each__ test. All methods with `@BeforeClass` are run only once, before any test. Generally, you set `static` stuff with `@BeforeClass` which is then re-used (so, tests are no longer independent). You set non-static stuff with `@Before`, and thus tests are independent. Just read the docs for these annotations.

Comment: `@BeforeClass` (JUnit 5: `@BeforeAll`) runs once for the whole test class, `@Before` (JUnit 5: `@BeforeEach`) runs before each single test method.

Comment: I use JUnit5, then I see the difference between `@BeforeEach` vs `@BeforeAll` well from your explanations. **However**, I am not sure if I should  or not clear the lists that are used by multiple test. I ay need to clear them in `@AfterEach`. Any idea?

Comment: Do not clear the list. It also sounds like you should toy around with this a little bit, because evidently an SO answer isn't sufficient for you. That's a good instinct! Just.. make some tests, add some elements to a list initialized only once in `@Before`, and print some stuff - without removing anything. Then simply observe what happens.

Comment: Yes, it could be played, but  I think it is a really common situation and there must be a general approach for that. So, I just need to be clarified about the Unit Test convention for re-using the same variables (e.g. just defining once in @BeforeEach **OR** @BeforeAll, clear the variables on  `@AfterEach`. So, what is the proper approach for this situation?. Any idea?

Comment: Use `@Before`. I have no idea what could possibly still be confusing you at this point. The answer spells it out!

Comment: Nice answer. Note that the `@BeforeClass` method must be static, and hence can only manipulate static fields. Your advice to avoid static fields is sound, and then, indeed, all one needs is `@Before`.